# What's the conventional directory for classes in an Ember project?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web-applications, directory-structure

If I create a custom class according to https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/classes-and-instances/,

e.g.

```
// person.js
import EmberObject from '@ember/object';

const Person = EmberObject.extend({
  say(thing) {
    alert(thing);
  }
});
```

Is there a conventional directory in the ember project for `person.js`?

None of these conventional directories seem quite right...

- **adapters/** (specific purpose)
- **components/** (specific purpose)
- **controllers/** (specific purpose)
- **helpers/** (specific purpose)
- **models/** (for actual DS Models)
- **routes/** (specific purpose)
- **styles/** (not js)
- **templates/** (not js)
- **serializers/** (specific purpose)
- **utils/** (too generic)

Comment: You are free to create new directory if you feel such need (I do, sometimes). But "conventional" place is "utils".

Answer (score 3):

Definitely `utils`. Utils is for anything that does not fit into any of the core ember categories.

Another way to think about it is, if you always have to import it to use it rather than letting the resolver load it, it should be in utils. There are lots of exceptions to this, like inheriting from things and using mixins, but as a general rule its a good starting point when thinking about what should be in utils.

From the docs:

> Ember utilities are reusable code that can be accessed from various parts of the application.

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/service/

I wouldn't call `utils` "too" generic. Your class sounds like something that will be reused in various parts of the application.

Comment: Yes, but what if one needs to store in separate file not code but some sort of config? For example, if we want to let users select color for some elements from predefined set, is `utils` the right place to store such set of colors? I'm not sure - it doesn't fit `utility` term, IMHO. For me, `util` associates with something executable (function that I can call or class that has some useful methods).

Comment: I’m not an ember core team member or anything, but thats what we do in our project. We just default export {} the json object for static config stuff